# `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` on a request with proxy

Tags: java, https

I am trying to send a HTTP POST request to a site with a HTTPS proxy.

I am currently doing it like that:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://example.com");

                    HttpHost proxy2 = new HttpHost("proxy ip here", 8080, "https");
                    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setProxy(proxy2)
                            .build();
                    request.setConfig(config);


                    String json = "\"" + username + "\"";
                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
                    request.setEntity(entity);
                    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request, context);

                    HttpEntity entityresponse = response.getEntity();
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entityresponse, "UTF-8");

                    response.close();
                    httpclient.close();
```

But I am getting this: `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

I've tried a lot of proxies and different URLs too but the same problem is there.

It work fine if I set a HTTP URL and the `http` parameter in the proxy host line, but I want HTTPS :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call https url, you must have to install the certificate in your jre security/lib folder.

In order to install the certificate, please follow below steps:

1. Download InstallCert.java file from : https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/180292346/InstallCert.java?version=1&modificationDate=1315453596921
2. copy InstallCert.java to any location.
3. run: javac InstallCert.java
4. run: java InstallCert example.com:port
5. jssecacerts file will be generated
6. Copy it inside JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security folder

I hope this should resolve your issue.